# mocking url.openStream() should return InputStream

Tags: java, junit, mocking, java-io

My actual class accepting URL as input and calling url.openStream(),this should return InputStream.

```
public static Map<String, Object> parseA(URL url) throws Exception {
   byte[] readData = new byte[25*1024*1024];
    // Here url.openStream() returning null
            InputStream is = url.openStream();

            while((readLength = is.read(readData, 0, 25*1024*1024)) != -1){
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new 
    ByteArrayInputStream(readData)));

                // All CW_* strings are collected first
}
```

My test class is

```
 @Rule
    public TemporaryFolder folder= new TemporaryFolder();
 @Test(enabled = true)
    public void parseATest() {

            File file=null;
           try {
             file =folder.newFile("testingData.txt");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

            final URLConnection mockConnection = EasyMock.createMock(URLConnection.class);
            final URLStreamHandler handler = new URLStreamHandler() {

                @Override
                protected URLConnection openConnection(final URL arg0)
                        throws IOException {
                    return mockConnection;
                }
            };
            URL url=null;
            try {
                url = new URL("http://foo.bar", "foo.bar", 80, "", handler);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            InputStream is=null;
            try {
                is = new FileInputStream(file);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e2.printStackTrace();
            } 
            try {
                EasyMock.expect(url.openStream()).andReturn(is).anyTimes();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        try {
             // imageHeaderParser is object of actual class
            imageHeaderParser.parseA(url);
        } catch (IfmSwimParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Here **TemporaryFolder** used to create temp file.And I dont want URL to go network.It can be just dummy URL and when i call url.openStream(),it should return stream of temp file i mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A file can be converted to an URL, so just do that :

```
Url testUrl = Paths.get("folder",("testingData.txt").toUri().toURL();
Map<String, Object> map = parseA(testUrl);
// assert map content
```

Besides you don't need any mock if you want to test with the file processing behavior.

Comment: Thanks @davidxxx, Could you please tell me where i can find this kind of info

Comment: You are welcome. Which kind of information you refer to ?

Comment: Related to files and new updates.Here file is not getting deleted after execution of test case.As per TEMPFOLDER it should be deleted right?

Comment: It should be deleted according to the java doc : https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html but that is not a mandatory thing : "Whether the deletion is successful or not is not checked by this rule. No exception will be thrown in case the deletion fails." Maybe the file is not deletable because it is still opened. You could check that.

Comment: it is not opened.Any way to delete that?